# Macro to Format Sheet(s) that Contain Specific Text

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro that formats an excel file.  I was curious if there was a way to have this format all sheets that contain a specific text in the title.  I'll have a workbook with numerous tab for various companies with a little different formatting requirements for each company and some months a few companies will be different.  If the sheets don't exist, then ignore and move on.....  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Worksheets("DEN BS Assets").Select

Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long



With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With


Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 12


Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Replace What:="X", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False





With ActiveSheet
.Select

    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    .DisplayPageBreaks = False


    Firstrow = 9
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row


    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1


        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                Select Case .Value
                Case Is = "Denver", "Inactive", "System:": .EntireRow.Delete
                End Select


            End If


        End With

    Next Lrow

End With



With ActiveSheet
.Select

    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    .DisplayPageBreaks = False


    Firstrow = 7
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row


    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1


        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                Select Case .Value
                Case Is = "Net Change", "Account:": .EntireRow.Insert
                End Select

            End If


        End With

    Next Lrow

End With



With ActiveSheet.Select

    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    .DisplayPageBreaks = False


    Firstrow = 7
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row


    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1


        With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

            If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                Select Case .Value
                Case Is = "Net Change", "Totals:": .EntireRow.Delete
                End Select

            End If


        End With

    Next Lrow

    End With





  Range("A50000").Select
 Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
 Selection.EntireRow.Insert

 Range("A50000").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight


   Range("A50000").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

 Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 20



With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$8"
.Orientation = xlLandscape
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = False
End With

 Rows("9:9").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True`
```

Comment: Do you mean specific text in the sheet name? What specific text?

Comment: Yes- "Denver 1" "Denver 2" Denver 3" so formatting any sheet with "Denver" is what I am hoping for.   Number of sheets change and i am hoping to produce this for other companies that may be available in the month.  Sometimes "New York" but not every month so hoping the macro can format if it exists but skip if not available.  Thank you.

Comment: OK, suggested answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code, remove some unnecessary Select statements (although not all as wasn't sure what the end section does). Also don't think you need two loops to insert and then delete rows.

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Denver*" Then
        ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ws.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 12

        ws.Columns("A:A").Replace What:="X", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False

        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        With ws
           .DisplayPageBreaks = False
            Firstrow = 9
            Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
            For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
                With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                    If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                        Select Case .Value
                        Case Is = "Denver", "Inactive", "System:": .EntireRow.Delete
                        End Select
                    End If
                End With
            Next Lrow
        End With

        With ws
            Firstrow = 7
            For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
                With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                    If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                        Select Case .Value
                        Case Is = "Net Change", "Account:": .EntireRow.Insert
                        End Select
                    End If
                End With
            Next Lrow
        End With

        With ws
            For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
                With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                    If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                        Select Case .Value
                        Case Is = "Net Change", "Totals:": .EntireRow.Delete
                        End Select
                    End If
                End With
            Next Lrow
        End With

        ws.Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Resize(, 2).Insert shift:=xlToRight
        ws.Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Insert shift:=xlToRight
        ws.Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 20

        With ws.PageSetup
            .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$8"
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
        End With

        ws.Rows("9:9").Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Definitely seems to be on the right track.  The macro keeps debugging at ws.Range("A50000").Select.  Any ideas for the error?

Comment: Oops as a stopgap add 'ws.select' before that line. Will come back with something better once back at computer.

Comment: That seems to fix the whole thing.  Thank you so much!  I took a macro course but this world is a bit complex.  I'm going to see if I can incorporate this into the other companies.

Comment: I've put a proper fix in now so you can remove the `ws.select` line. If this works, I'd be grateful if you would accept it as an answer.

Comment: Nice, this works and thank you so much.  You saved so much time automating these reports!

Comment: Thanks glad it helped.